# Discord.js Poll Command Cannot read property '0' of null

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a Discord.js poll command I keep getting this error Cannot read property '0' of null and help would be appreciated. I don't have any idea how to fix I've tried a lot of different ways around and they all didn't work :(

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')
module.exports = {
    name : 'poll',
    category : 'util',
    cooldown: 5,
    description : 'Makes a poll',
    permissions: ["MANAGE_MESSAGES"],


    run : async(client, message, args) => {
let num = {
    1: '1️⃣',
    2: '2️⃣',
    3: '3️⃣',
    4: '4️⃣',
    5: '5️⃣',
    6: '6️⃣',
    7: '7️⃣',
    8: '8️⃣',
    9: '9️⃣',
    10: ''
}

var questionRe = /"(.*)"/gmi
        let question = args.join(" ").match(questionRe)

        if (!questionRe) return message.args("You did not provide question")
        let options = args.join(" ").slice(question[0].length).split(" | ")
        let result = ""
        
        
        if (options.length <= 1) {
            result += "✅ : Yes\n"
            result += "❌ : No"

            return message.send(` ${question}`, `React with one of the following to determine your choice!\n${result}`, "BLUE").then(async msg => {
                await msg.react("✅")
                await msg.react("❌")
            })

        } else {
            if (options.length > 9) return message.error("Cannot be more than 9 options")
            result = options.map((c, i) => {
                return `${num[i + 1]}: ${c}`
            })
            let msg = await message.sendE(` ${question}`, `React with one of the following to determine your choice!\n${result.join('\n')}`, "BLUE")
            options.map(async (c, x) => {
                await msg.react(num[x + 1])
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide how input look like I know what happen but for completely solution I need more information

Answer (score 0):

In this line the thing you should check is `question` instead of `questionRe`

```js
        if (!question || question.length === 0) return message.args("You did not provide question")
```

Comment: Adding on, the second check is redundant. A string with a length of `0` is falsey and will always be caught by `!question`.

Comment: Did you write some code and test?. `!question` will not work with empty array like [] test it

Comment: If `question` is a string my comment still applies, `.join()` is called on the array of `args`

Comment: It will be array :D  Cause there is last .match() out there

Comment: I see, I still haven't touched on Regex.